# springboot switch datasource after startup

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

can I config datasource like:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: .....
  sec-datasource:
    url: .....
```

can springboot switch datasource after startup? less code will be better

I have two different credential for same database instance with different permission,
When starting the application I want to use first credential `spring.datasource.url`, after startup I want to switch to another credential `spring.sec-datasource.url` to handle CRUD

springboot version is 2.5.14, we about to upgrade the version so future solution is acceptable as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple profile

application-local.yml

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: .....
```

application-dev.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: .....
```

then specified by the `spring.profiles.active` property.